# What movie is this? A black, slick, oil-like monster, similar to The Blob but liquid like

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I will guess this movie was from between 1960-70, not sure. I was a small kid and it gave me nightmares.

The monster is like *The Blob*, but an oil slick/slime that went about and ate/dissolved people. All that would be left behind was their clothing. I think a part of movie took place on a boat, oil rig or something out in ocean. I want to say that maybe it was even from 1950's because I think the men were wearing business suits and hats. I also think it was black and white, not sure.

It is not a *Star Trek* episode. It is not *The Raft.*

Comment: It might be "The H-Man" but am not sure, I don't recall it being Japanese Movie

Comment: I really want to say it was the [oil slick virus](http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/Purity) (aka Purity) from X-Files, especially because one episode concerning said virus involves a black-and-white flashback to an encounter with it aboard an American submarine in 1945. However, the black oil virus infected/possessed people, rather than dissolving them.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question and noted the link to this question so here I am. So this is more information on the movie... I remember watching a black and white movie as a kid that scared the bejesus out of me. I don't remember the origin of the creature but it was an amoeba like creature that dissolved human flesh and bone (leaving only the clothes). It was flat, unlike "The Blob" and so was hard to see coming. It also could climb walls and drop down on you from the ceiling. They found out that it was living in the sewers and (I think) poured oil down there and ignited it. The actors

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your outline it indeed sounds like the Japanese movie The H-Man. It was released in English as well in the US.

Some notable plot points that led me to the conclusion are:

1. The first part of the movie takes place on a boat, Ryujin Maru, which goes missing and is found later by crew of another boat. When the crew board Ryujin Maru they see only clothes.
2. One by one they are then attacked and dissolved to death by the oily-sticky monster goop (which can also take human shape.) When the bodies of victims are melted away only clothes are left behind. Only two people are able to escape alive from the ship.

You can refresh your memory [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051413/). :)

P.S. The movie is indeed from late 1950's (1959 to be exact.)

Answer (score 2):

It kinda sounds like one of the stories from Creepshow 2. The only thing was that I don't think that it left any clothes when it ate the people that were on the raft.

Comment: Good start. At this point, you could add some screenshots to support your answer. However, this question already has an accepted answer, and this being a story-id question, there is now no need for new answers.

Comment: I know, but it is a good way to practice on giving a good answer.

Comment: Then you could proceed with adding that screenshot ;)